# JFrog CLI is giving me a "Wrong number of arguments" error using the Artifactory Maven build step in Azure DevOps (VSTS)

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm new to Azure DevOps (VSTS) and I'm attempting to set up a new Pipeline build using the Artifactory Maven build step. When running the build I get the following error:

> 2018-09-12T20:59:02.0861829Z ##[error]Error: Command failed: D:\a_jfrog\1.19.1\jfrog.exe rt mvn "install -f D:\a\1\s\pom.xml" D:\a\1\s\config --build-name="SomeProject-Maven-CI" --build-number="20180912.6"
>
> 2018-09-12T20:59:02.0988256Z [Error] Wrong number of arguments. You can read the documentation at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI

I found this info on GitHub: https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/issues/165

Its a similar error but not quite the same. I'm not sure how to edit the command that Azure Pipeline is running or even if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue. I had a space included in my build name and it apparently the JFrog Cli didn't like that. When I removed the space the error went away. Other errors came up but that's off-topic from this question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please report the errors your encountered in Artifactory VSTS extension's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-vsts-extension/issues)?
We'll really appreciate it.

Update: A pull request opened to target this issue. You can track it [here](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-vsts-extension/pull/40).

Update 2: Fixed in latest release 1.4.0.